# Should * be escaped in bash when it is used inside double braces to perform multiplication?

Tags: bash, escaping

I thought * should be escaped in bash when it is to be used in a meaning other than the universal character, for example I am trying to use * to multiply two numbers. But when I am trying to use * with an escape character I am getting an error.

```
echo "scale=2; 10 \* 3" | bc

EOF encountered in a comment.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

but when I am not using the escape character it works.

```
echo "scale=2; 10 * 3" | bc

30
```

why is this? Can someone explain?

Comment: Fixing the typo changes the error reported by `bc`.

Comment: `"..."` are quotation marks, not braces (`{...}`).

Answer (score 0):

You would use `\` to escape the `*`, not `/`, but no, you do not need to escape it. `bash` is not doing the multiplication; it's simply writing a string to the standard input of `bc`.

The double quotes *already* escape `*` from being interpreted by the shell.

```
echo "scale=2; 10 * 3"
```

is equivalent to

```
echo scale=2\;\ 10\ \*\ 3
```

Regarding the error message in your first attempt, `bc` scripts allow C-style comments, so `/*` was interpreted as the start of a comment that was never completed before the end of the script.